# Onsite javaCode VS .js file

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

In my process of learing java, I've discovered some code can be kept on a dedicated .js file, while other must remain on the page in question, with the prior making life easier when updating mulitple pages.
My issue is the following code:

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.one").click(function(){
$("img").removeClass("border_blue"),
$("img").addClass("border_red"),
 ...etc,etc,etc ;`
```

it would be nice if this code could be referenced via the normal:
`<script type="text/javascript" src=../myjava.js"></script>`

Researching into this, I believe my issue is the first line of code:
`$(document).ready(function(){`

I believe this is what requires it to remain on the page in question, and not linkable.

Can I get some info on how to rewrite the code to make it linkable?

....see above

Comment: If you're learning JavaScript, you're not learning Java.

Comment: Also no, the reason you're having an issue is that your code needs to run **after** you've imported jQuery into the page. Being an inline script has absolutely nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: k, so let me rephrase, ...Can i keep the same code and still link it, or is the language all wrong for what i need?

Comment: Well, you didn't even post what error or bad behavior you're encountering, but a good bet is that you're trying to use jQuery (via the `$()` function) **before** it has been imported into the page. The **order** of your `<script>` elements in the page is important, but whether they're inline or not isn't important.

Comment: If you import jQuery into a page, with a `<script>` tag that comes before any other script that uses it (inline or not, doesn't matter), then the code will work. One more time: inline or not inline, the script code will be treated the same (except for `async` and `deferred` scripts, which I assume you are not using).

Answer (score 0):

finally found my error - and it was exactly as you mentioned - I appreciate the help!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).